# Apply loop to check if value is equal between ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight a cell if it doesn't equal the value defined in a worksheet range.

I am checking each cell in the range "ADS_Export[ADS_208_SZ]" against `Worksheets(ADS_Validator").Range("E3:E500")` but it doesn't like the range E3:E500.

Seems to work if I just put E3 but all after the first cell check are incorrect as its checking against the third row, not the next row in the worksheet range (E4 etc.).

It needs to check the first value in the ADS_Export range against the first value in the worksheet range which starts at E3 and then does the next one. Also, need to redefine to highlight if not equal instead of equal.

Only just getting into VBA so my knowledge is very limited.

```
Sub IF_Loop()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("ADS_Export[ADS_208_SZ]")
        If cell.Value = Worksheets("ADS_Validator").Range("E:E").Value Then
            cell.Interior.Color = 65535
        End If
    Next cell 
End Sub
```

Comment: This part of the code `If cell.Value = Worksheets("ADS_Validator").Range("E:E").Value` does not make sense. A second iteration is necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub IF_Loop()
    Dim cell As Range, celVal As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Worksheets("ADS_Validator").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(XlUp).row
    For Each cell In Range("ADS_Export[ADS_208_SZ]")
        For Each cellval In Worksheets("ADS_Validator").Range("E3:E" & lastRow)
            If cel.value = celVal.value Then
                 cell.Interior.Color = 65535
            End If
        Next
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tried that code. There seemed to be a problem with the references (celVal and cell names had variations on different lines) which I fixed and it ran but then it just crashes. Not sure what is going on. the celVal range needs to start at E3 and it's unknown how many rows it will go down but it will be a maximum of 500. Think this might be beyond my capability at this point.

Comment: @A.Denis: I just took your rages as they were. It would be much better to also limit the "E:E" range.  I will create a variable to determine the last filled row and update the code. What range "ADS_Export[ADS_208_SZ]" is, in fact?